# How to say that you were accepted/rejected from a college in Mandarin?

Tags: translation, meaning, expressions

For example, how would I say something like "Harvard rejected me" or "Harvard accepted me"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

reject: 拒绝, 驳回, 否决, 否认

Harvard rejected me.
哈佛拒绝了我。
哈佛大学拒绝了我的申请。

accept: 接受, 答应, 采纳, 采用, 接纳, 录取

Harvard accepted me.
哈佛录取了我。
哈佛录取我了。
哈佛大学接受了我的申请。

Answer (score 0):

Probably the OP is thinking of 錄取. This is the verb that means 'admit'; 'give a place in a class', 'allow to register as a full-time student.' It is perhaps more common (in China) to say something like 考進某大學, meaning you have passsed the admission exam or just 進某大學 'to enter or get into a university'

The opposite of 錄取 is simply 沒有錄取, there is no separate verb such as 'reject'. It is also of course possible that a school accepts/rejects your application for a job, or even accepts/rejects you or your ideas as good/smart/moral etc. These senses one would not use 錄取, but other words such as 聘請 or 雇用人 for jobs,  or 接收人 for your moral probity or fellowship.

Comment: Since the acception or rejection is, from the student's point of view, very passive, I would perhaps say 'I have been accepted/rejected by X uni.' Is it ok to say: 我被某大学录取了/不被录取？

Comment: 我被录取了。/我没被录取。You should not say 我不被录取。